# setTimeout is not being called from unit tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, qunit, sinon

Im working on typescript for my project where Im using QUint and sinonjs for unit-tests. One of my functions dynamically renders UI. I need to get the width of this dynamically rendered element and use that for some other computation. In order to ensure that width is computed right, Im using setTimeout. The code looks like this:

```
public function1(): void { 
this._createShowMoreUI();
    setTimeout(delegate(this, this.function2), 0);
}

private function2(): void { 
    // use this._element.width();
}
```

Everything works fine in general. But when function1 is invoked from a unit-test function2 is never being called. Googling just pointed me to how setTimeout can be mocked out or cases where in setTimeout was being wrongly used (as in setTimeout(function2(),0)) which was not of any help.

Comment: Can you show us the test? Without that we're just guessing at what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is probably working fine and what you need to do is enable `async` for the test. For Qunit you need to call `assert.async();`

docs: http://api.qunitjs.com/async/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes this was the problem. I had to use async: true. Figured that out, but forgot to update the thread. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

sinonjs provides 'Faking time' api for this, try something like below:

```
clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
//execute your code which contains setTimeout function herer
clock.tick();
assert();
clock.restore();
```